# actionscript 3 - how to put .swf on a mobile device?

Tags: android, flash, actionscript-3, flash-cs5

i have asked this question before but the answer received was not applicable in my situation. I searched the net and still unable to find anything. I have a game in flash actionscript 3.0 and i would like to put it on my htc hero - android phone. Are there any tutorials that state on how to do this please?

thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Generally speaking, you want to make a standalone apk using the Adobe Air paradigm (i.e. you do not put a .swf on the device).
http://www.adobe.com/products/air/sdk/
http://www.adobe.com/devnet/devices.html
Adobe will be rolling Android support into Flash (using the Air paradigm) starting with CS5.5 to be released in Q2 2011; the public beta they released in November 2010 (for CS5) is no longer available: http://labs.adobe.com/technologies/flashpro_extensionforair/

Answer (score 1):

You can do it using Flash CS5. There is an option to start a new "AIR for Android" project. You can use the code from your existing game. You may have to tweak parts of an existing game because mobile devices are less powerfull, and have different inputs like touchscreens, virtual keyboards and menu buttons.

Answer (score 0):

No tutorials come to mind. If I were to search Google, my luck would probably be as good as yours.

I have been recently writing a mobile application using Adobe's Preview of Flash Builder Burrito.  There is a project creation option in there to create an Action Script Mobile Application which is exactly perfect for what you are asking in your question.

I assume that the Actionscript game is written by you so you will have no problem moving it into the project created by Flash Builder Burrito.

In fact, I think Adobe just released the final version of Flash Builder Burrito, and you can download it as a fully functional free 60 day trial. That should be more than enough time to bundle up your game and deploy it to the Android app store, or just debug it on your own phone for yourself. Adobe also gives out free licenses for students, and unemployed developers.

Hope this helps.  Let me know if you have any trouble it should be very straight forward to wrap up your game and get it on your Android phone.